# one click single sign on google market place

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I have published an application that can be installed from Google market place(only admin can install) once the domain admin installed the app domains users should be able to login to app without asking him any permission (Consent Screen)

The flow i have implemented is Whenever my app icon is clicked from Gmail it uses Universal Navigation URL to hit admin console which then redirect to callback URL,at the endpoint i can able to get list of information related to the scopes that i have included in scope list(Both in market place console and Universal URL). But OAuth2.0 authroization screen is getting displayed to each user for the first time. It should not behave like that, Since the administrator has installed the app, domain users should not ask for permission.

--
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you are seeing is not the OAuth authorization screen but rather the OpenID authorization screen.  Since accessing the app means that the individual user is sharing data about *themselves* to the relying party (your application) they need to authorize that OpenID connection.